# Multibyte String replacement (Only if completely String)

Tags: regex, string, replace, preg-replace

I'm searching for a way to replace strings only if the completely string matches the needle and not only a pharse of the string.

Currently I'm using this:

```
$string = mb_eregi_replace('(^|\b)Battlefield(\b|$)', $string . ' (BF)', $string);
```

In: `Battlefield 1` - Out: `Battlefield 1 (BF) 1`

Or another example:

```
$string = mb_eregi_replace('(^|\b)Call Of Duty(\b|$)', $string . '(CoD)', $string);
$string = mb_eregi_replace('(^|\b)Call Of Duty 2 Mac(\b|$)', 'Call Of Duty 2 (CoD)', $string);
```

In: `Call Of Duty 2 Mac(CoD) 2 Mac` - Out: `Call Of Duty 2 Mac(CoD) 2 Mac`

But I'm searching for something else...

1. I want to **add** (BF) or (CoD) at the end of every string who contains the word "Battlefield" or "Call of Duty"
2. And I want to only to replace strings with other string, like above, of the holy string matches the pattern and not only a excerpt... Example:

My String is `"Battlefield 1 Day One"`. And my needle is `Battlefield 1`. And I **don't want** to replace this string because not the **holy** string matches the needle, but only a excerpt... As you can see, my pattern above doesn't work... Does anyone has an idea how I can implement my both question?

Greetings and Thank You!

Comment: Start of string - `^`, end of string - `$` (or `\z`).

Comment: But as you can see, my pattern doesn't work: `(^|\b)...(\b|$)`

Comment: Yes, because `(^|\b)Call Of Duty(\b|$)` = `\bCall Of Duty\b`. You need  `^Call Of Duty$` to match a `Call Of Duty` as a whole string.

Comment: So I just must remove the `\b` tags and then it is working? -> Like this `(^)Call Of Duty($)`?

Comment: And whats about my first question?

Comment: Aha, so those were 2 questions in one making it too broad. Just use `preg_replace('~.*\bCall of Duty\b.*~isu', '$0 (CoD)', $s)`.

Comment: But I need a multibyte working pattern!

Comment: Yes, it is one.